# texi2pdf or texi2dvi in TexLive?

Tags: texlive, texinfo

This question originates from my question on StackOverflow, available here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34916057/5782687

The problem, it seems to be, boils down to TeXLive not including an executable `texi2pdf.exe` which is why I've turned to tex.stackexchange to ask how I can install/get/acquire such a thing as it appears to be TeX specific. It comes pre-packaged with MiTeX, so there should surely be a way to get it for TeXLive too?

In the link here: http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/tools/texi2pdf it says:

> MiKTeX has a texi2dvi executable but no other Windows TeX installation that we know of does, so emulation is used on e.g. TeXLive installations on Windows.

I have read the texinfo package documentation, [found here](https://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/texinfo/html_node/Preparing-for-TeX.html), but alas I'm none the wiser. I was also looking through bug reports lodged when MiTeX dropped texinfo support (for a short period only), but I didn't find a work around for Windows and texi2pdf is now supported again in MiTeX (tried it today on another machine).

---

I'm running Windows 10 and recently upgraded my TeX distribution to TeXLive 2015. For those who use R and TeXLive, the actual code I'm trying to run is:

```
library(shiny)
runGist('https://gist.github.com/yihui/6091942')
```

Any help is extremely welcome, I don't want to change up my entire workflow just so I can use `knit2pdf` (which calls `tools::texi2pdf`) in R...

Comment: why is R using a texinfo script to process latex documents, that seems weird.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't think `texi2any` is in TeX Live. Not on mine, at least.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm using `knit2pdf` from the `knitr` package and it does call `texi2pdf` (which I found was the source of my problem on S.O.)... the only way I could change this is to build my own `knit2pdf` function

Comment: @egreg oops I have `texi2any` but looks like it came with cygwin not via texlive, I deleted first comment. But in any case it sounds like a bug in the R package if it is looking for texi2zzzz scripts to process latex source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, the statement about `texi2dvi` and Windows is plain wrong. W32TeX (http://w32tex.org/) also ships it. `texi2dvi` is a script from the `texinfo` package, which is not included in TeX Live because it should be packaged independently as it provides also the `info` reader and other tools not really related (for example it does create `.info` pages without using an TeX engine).

I guess all Linux distributions ship the texinfo package in one way or another, so it is easy to get there. Recent texinfo is heavily based on Perl, so I am not aware of an independent distribution for Windows, but as long as you search for a bit older one (4.13) then gnuwin32 is good enough a source.

Comment: To close off this question in case any one else comes across this, I formatted my hard drive to dual boot with Ubuntu and reinstalled my TeX distro as MikTeX not TeXLive. I can confirm what norbert said - works fine with Windows & MiTeX and works fine with Ubuntu & TexLive.

Comment: I don't understand. If a Windows user with Texlive needs texinfo to get texi2pdf, then what are we supposed to tell that person? How to get it?

Comment: Version 4.13a is available for Windows: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/texinfo.htm Other than this there is the recomenndation to install Perl and texinfo. I haven't seen a good guided tour, though. And AFAIK no out-of-the-box distribution for Windows.